# Selenium webdriver cannot get an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to create a crawler/scraper. And the element which I want to crawl, In my opinion serving JS.
And on my browser I can see that element but on webdriver I cannot see this.

For example;
URL : https://www.hotic.com.tr/p/hakiki-deri-camel-erkek-cuzdan-168675?_sgm_campaign=scn_2a06ce3c78082000&_sgm_source=168675&_sgm_action=click

And On my browser I can see element like that:

[image: Image from my browser]

But on chrome webdriver I cannot see that element like that:

[image: Image from web driver]

And my webdriver code like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.hotic.com.tr/p/hakiki-deri-camel-erkek-cuzdan-168675?_sgm_campaign=scn_2a06ce3c78082000&_sgm_source=168675&_sgm_action=click")
driver.quit()
```

On my browser I just click the URL. I have no user account or promo code.

How can I get this element on webdriver chrome?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please mentioned which value you want to fetch and what problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value `Sepette %30 İndirim: 153.30 TL` use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following `css selector`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.hotic.com.tr/p/hakiki-deri-camel-erkek-cuzdan-168675?_sgm_campaign=scn_2a06ce3c78082000&_sgm_source=168675&_sgm_action=click")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.ins-discount-badge"))).text)
```

**Output on console:**

```
Sepette %30 İndirim: 153.30 TL
```